# HTTP2 with HAProxy

Tags: apache, centos, haproxy, http2

We are using HaProxy as a reverse proxy, SSL certifications are installed in the Load Balancer (SSL offloading).
In the backend we have some websites using shopware and typo3 .

We have enabled HTTP2 in HAproxy in order to improve the performance of our websites.

The website using (typo3) crashed after few hours, the load average in the webserver increased to high level: 25-30 with many HTTPD process !!
I got some error from log file (too many connections to the DB...).

I've added some resources to the webserver (20 GB of RAM, 8 CPU ), the server resist but it finally crashed.

Other websites using shoupware works fine...

I'm not sure if this is related to our architecture or there is something to be changed in the backend (Apache or typo3).

OS:Centos7
HA-Proxy version 1.8.14-52e4d43
Webserrver apache

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have set any limits that haproxy can protect the Apache HTTPD with mod_php for the overload?

Comment: No, But everything works fine with HTTP1, when i enable HTTP2 in Haproxy:alpn h2,http/1.1, the number of HTTPD process increase suddenly in the webserver, and the load average become too high too...

Comment: I suspect it would have to do with the increased load due to how HTTP/2 does multiplexing and header compression, but I have trouble thinking that it'd still crash with the added resources. Is any particular resource spiking? CPU, Mem? What's the config look like for HAProxy and Apache?

Comment: @ramslim does lowering the value of `tune.h2.max-concurrent-streams` (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.2-tune.h2.max-concurrent-streams) to something like 6 or 10 help?

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your replies, since i have the same configuration working with other website using other CMS (Shopware), i assume that the problem come from the backend (typo3), We are checking the configuration there, i'll inform you if the problem is fixed. @CarloMencarelli: yes, for sure the load is due to multiplexing..